# Error when creating a DataScroller inside Composite Component

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, composite-component

I have a composite component with a dataScroller inside (tomahawk). In my xhtml I tried to use this component but I receive an error:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: could not find UIData referenced by attribute dataScroller@for = 'myTable'

The component:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
    xmlns:t="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk">
<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="for" targets="scroll"></composite:attribute>
    <composite:attribute name="paginatorMaxPages" />
</composite:interface>

<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <composite:implementation>

        <div class="paginacao">
            <t:dataScroller id="scroll" for="#{cc.attrs.for}"
                styleClass="paginador" renderFacetsIfSinglePage="false"
                pageIndexVar="numeroPagina" pageCountVar="quantidadePaginas"
                rowsCountVar="quantidadeRegistros" paginator="true"
                paginatorMaxPages="#{cc.attrs.paginatorMaxPages}"
                paginatorTableClass="paginasPaginador"
                paginatorActiveColumnClass="negrito">

                <f:facet name="first">#{labels['paginacao.primeira']}</f:facet>
                <f:facet name="previous">#{labels['paginacao.anterior']}</f:facet>
                <f:facet name="next">#{labels['paginacao.proxima']}</f:facet>
                <f:facet name="last">#{labels['paginacao.ultima']}</f:facet>
            </t:dataScroller>
        </div>

    </composite:implementation>
</h:body>
</html>
```

My datatable:

```
<h:form>
 ...
    <t:dataTable id="myTable" var="item" value="#{mBean.lista}">
 ...
    </t:dataTable>
 ...
</h:form>       

<param:parametrosScroll id="dataScroller" for="myTable" paginatorMaxPages="5" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To ensure reusability of multiple instances in the same view, composite components are inherently naming containers, like `<h:form>`, `<h:dataTable>`, etc. In your specific case, the relative client ID in `for="myTable"` will be searched in the context of `<cc:implementation>`, but there is no such component. Instead, it's outside the composite, in another naming container represented by `<h:form>`.

You've 2 options:

1. Pass an absolute client ID after having given the `<h:form>` a fixed ID.

   ```
   for=":myForm:myTable"
   ```
2. [Use a tagfile instead of a composite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822000/when-to-use-uiinclude-tag-files-composite-components-and-or-custom-componen).

Comment: I used a tagfile. Thanks.